# How to split strings based on characters either side of the character being split

Tags: javascript, split

I have an array of strings (example below) which is being looped and I need to be able to get the last ID and Name.

```
/18264:Blues (all)/19307:Acoustic Blues
/18264:Blues (all)/19308:Blues
/18267:Dance/Electronica
```

From the above example, I want to achieve this:

```
id: 19307
name: Acoustic Blues

id: 19308
name: Blues

id: 18267
name: Dance/Electronica
```

So it's getting the last id and name however I have issues with names that have slashes in them (IE Dance/Electronica) is there a way to ignore that slash? My code is below (example):

```
angular.forEach(obj, function(val, key) {
    // /18264:Blues (all)/19307:Acoustic Blues
    var str = key.split('/').pop();
    // 19307
    var id = str.split(':')[0];
    // Acoustic Blues
    var name = str.split(':')[1];

    newObj.push({ 'id': id, 'name': name });
}
```

Let me know what you think!

Carl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where regular expressions can help - they're designed for matching patterns in strings such as this.  For this problem, you can use the following regex:

```
\/(\d+):([^:]*)$
```

This is made up of:

- `\/` - an escaped `/` - the starting slash
- `(\d+)` - at least one digit, inside a capturing group, to capture the ID
- `:` - literally a colon
- `([^:]*)` - a capturing group looking for anything *other* than a colon, to capture the name
- `$` - the end of the string

To use this in your code, you can do so as follows:

```
angular.forEach(obj, function(val, key) {
    //note the extra / at the start and end, denoting this as a regular expression
    //in javascript
    var result = /\/(\d+):([^:]*)$/.exec(key);
    var id = result[1];
    var name = result[2];

    newObj.push({ 'id': id, 'name': name });
}
```

`result` is an array, where indices 1 and 2 correspond to the capturing groups in the regex.

For a visualisation of what's happening, and more of a breakdown of the regular expression, there are a number of online tools such as [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/efjPwt/1) which can help.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the in-depth explanation - looks like I'll be needing to get myself into some regex! Worked perfectly, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
var lines = ["/18264:Blues (all)/19307:Acoustic Blues", "/18264:Blues (all)/19308:Blues", "/18267:Dance/Electronica"];

var newObj = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
  var line = lines[i].split(/:/);
  newObj.push({"id" : line[line.length - 2].split(/\//)[1], "name" : line.slice(-1)[0]});
}

console.log(newObj);
```